# Software Center gives me an "Error scanning the CD: Could not find a suitable CD"

Tags: 12.04, apt, software-center, repository, software-sources

I am getting the "Could not find a suitable CD" error every time I open *Software Sources* in order to add a PPA. A picture can be found below:

[image]

How do I solve this problem? I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I see your mouse is near `Add volume`. If you are clicking it, that is the wrong button. You need to click `Add` near the left instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see your mouse is near `Add volume`. If you are clicking it, that is the wrong button. You need to click `Add` near the left instead.

[image: The wise <code>Add</code> button]

Comment: I'm surprised this is upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

In that same tab from the screenshot, look for "Cdrom with Ubuntu 12.04 'Precise Pangolin'" and uncheck it. I had two of them in mine. After that it should work. Otherise, please post all of your external repos as there may be an issue with one of them:

```
tail -n +1 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

and

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```